# Is there a Word Lens alternative/port for Android?

Tags: languages, translate

**Any idea [how we can do this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2OfQdYrHRs) in Android?**

For those of you at work who can't watch the video, it's a demo of an iPhone app that came out today called Word Lens, which in translates language in real-time through the camera.  If you point it at a sign in Spanish, it doesn't just output a translated text, it makes it look as though the sign were in English.  Un-freaking-believable!

The closest thing I have seen is Google Goggles but I don't think it even comes close to Word Lens.  Am I missing anything?  Do we have any awesomeness like this yet?

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment - my coworker promptly downloaded the app on his iPhone4 and we started experimenting -- The OCR was very slow and unreliable and the text overlay was glaringly obvious when it was occasionally in the correct spot -- often it was randomly placed halfway across the viewfinder. In other words -- Don't fall in love with that demo just yet, it was clearly idealized. :) I found that Google Goggles, while not realtime, was far more accurate at OCR in our handful of informal tests this afternoon.

Comment: I actually have friends who worked on a virtually identical app.  I don't think it worked in real-time, though.  I'll ask them if they've seen this.

Comment: Google Goggles is pretty close, not real time, but I've had it translate a Japanese symbol for me before.

Comment: @Saiboogu: I suspected that might be the case.  Thanks for quelling my brief bout of iphone-envy.

Comment: @Matthew Read:  Was it an Android app or was it also for iOS?

Comment: @Matt Not sure, I'll check back when I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Google Goggles](http://www.appbrain.com/app/google-goggles/com.google.android.apps.unveil) is as good as it's going to get for now.  From what I've read in the comments and around the web it sounds like that Word Lens video makes the app look a lot better than it actually is.  For now it looks like Goggles, while it may not be in real-time is a more accurate option.

Comment: There is slightly more about its translation capabilities on the official page http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#text and http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=181356&cbid=-1o9yv01p3rz4g&src=cb&lev=%20answer

Answer (score 2):

Google acquired the [company behind the app "Word Lens"](http://questvisual.com).

Now [Google Translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate) incorporates the functionality of real time camera translation.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

[CamTranslator](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.intsig.camdict) seems to be a good app that can recognize and translate up to 14 languages, including Chinese (Simplified), Chinese (Traditional), English, French, Spanish, Portuguese, German, Italian, Dutch, Swedish, Finnish, Danish, Norwegian, Hungarian and etc.