# App that translate text from your camera?

Tags: applications, translate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word Lens Alternative/Port for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/word-lens-alternative-port-for-android)

Basically, I'm interested whether there is an Android app that does what [Word Lens](http://lifehacker.com/5714465/word-lens-translates-any-text-your-camera-can-see-on-the-fly) does for the iPhone.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/word-lens-alternative-port-for-android

Comment: Let's close it then. (I can't vote to close my own question :()